# Retrieving elements with preceding-sibling non-empty text nodes in XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Given test html:

```
<html>
<body>
  abc
  <b id="b_1">def</b>
  ghi
  <b id="b_2">jkl</b>
  <b id="b_3">mno</b><b id="b_4">qrs</b>
</body>
</html>
```

Question: How can i select all `b` elements whose first preceding-sibling node **are non-empty text nodes**?

So, in the example above, I wish to select elements `b_1` and `b_2`.

Element `b_3` has first preceding sibling node of type text, but it's empty.

Element `b_4` has first preceding sibling node that is element node.

---

I've tried the following, but they both fail in at least one respect:

- `preceding-sibling::*[1]` will select the first element node, ignoring the desired text nodes.
- `preceding-sibling::text()[1]` will select the first text node skipping any element nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//b[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()][.!='']]
```

will select all `b` elements whose immediately preceding sibling is a non-empty text node:

```
<b id="b_1">def</b>
<b id="b_2">jkl</b>
```

as requested.

Answer (score -1):

This one should work:

```
//b[normalize-space(./preceding-sibling::text()[1])]
```

The `normalize-space` function is the one checking that something exists there, because the `preceding-sibling` could be empty or even just a `\n`.

Comment: Running this in BaseX (which should be a superset of an XPath processor), I get all four `b` elements returned.

Comment: @eLRuLL, please read my post. By using "preceding-sibling::text()[1]" you ignore all element nodes until you meet your first text node.

Comment: @eLRuLL, ...I'm assuming that in the environment where you tested this, you have a parser that creates text nodes containing only whitespace? That's certainly not the case everywhere; with `lxml`, for example, it depends on the optional parser flag `remove_blank_text`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: His answer is incorrect because it fails for cases where the first preceding sibling node is an element which itself is preceded by a non-empty text node.  For example, the selection would include  `<b id="b_3">mno</b>` if the whitespace before `<b id="b_3">mno</b>` were eliminated.  To test the immediately preceding node, use `preceding-sibling::node()[1]` and then test that *that* node is a `text()` node.   [**Full correct answer is here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48120982/290085)